# How to create a custom v-model on component using another component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-composition-api, v-model

I have a `Vue 2.7 Composition API` custom component that can have a `v-model`. The component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="ui-field">
    <label :for="id">{{ label }}{{ required ? '*' : '' }}</label>
    <the-mask
      :aria-errormessage="errorDescriptionId()"
      :aria-invalid="!!error ? 'true' : 'false'"
      :autocomplete="autocomplete"
      class="ui-input"
      :data-acting="is_acting"
      :disabled="disabled"
      :id="id"
      :mask="masks"
      :masked="masked"
      :required="required"
      :type="type"
      :v-model="model"
      @input="emitChange"
    />
    <i class="ui-field__locked fas fa-lock" v-if="disabled"></i>
    <p :id="errorDescriptionId()" v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { Ref, ref } from 'vue'
import type { UIMaskedInput } from './UIMaskedInput'
import useUiInput from '../UIInput/Core'

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<UIMaskedInput>(), { masked: false })
let model: Ref<any> = ref<any>(props.value)
const emit = defineEmits(['input'])

let { emitChange, errorDescriptionId } = useUiInput(props, emit)
</script>
```

Here you have its props and a composbale called "useUIInput"

```
export interface UIInput {
  autocomplete?: 'on' | 'off' | undefined
  disabled?: boolean | undefined
  error?: string | undefined
  id?: string | undefined
  is_acting?: boolean | undefined
  label?: string | undefined
  required?: boolean | undefined
  type?: 'text' | 'number' | undefined
  value?: any
}

export interface UIMaskedInput extends UIInput {
  masks: Array<string>
  masked?: boolean
}
```

```
import { UIInput } from './UIInput'

export default function useUiInput(props: UIInput, emit) {
  function emitChange(event: Event): void {
    emit('input', 'event.target.value')
  }

  function errorDescriptionId(): string | undefined {
    if (props.error === undefined) {
      return undefined
    }

    return `${!!props.id ? props.id : __generateRandomId()}-error`
  }

  function __generateRandomId(): string {
    const letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    let random_string = ''

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)
      random_string += letters.charAt(index)
    }

    return random_string
  }

  return { emitChange, errorDescriptionId }
}
```

It's a composable because it is used also by another custom input component, but the main difference from that one to this masked component is that the other is just an HTML input tag, while this has another component for input (a one that allows masking). For that simple input tag component, my custom `v-model` works properly, but for this one, I haven't yet found a way for it to work. If anyone has any ideas on how to, I am thankful if you can share.